# Continuous hits to the server with Jmeter

Tags: load-testing, jmeter

I have 100 threads in JMeter which I want to hit a server 12 times in a loop. But each time 100 threads will run and pause for 5 seconds and then resume hitting the servers for next 100 times.

Here is how I tried:

[image]

But it is not considering **Startup Delay 15 seconds** but only for the first time. I want to have a delay after every 100 threads executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a child to Thread Group add Loop Controller and put everything other inside that Loop Controller. At the end of Loop Controller add Constant Timer. It should work that way.